# Hide “Quick Access” entry in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Making "Quick Access" search field optional is a long-awaited feature in Eclipse. Now this is possible according to the Eclipse Luna project [site](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna). My question is: how we can remove it? I found no option for it in the settings or the perspective customization.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can right-click on the Quick Access toolbar and select `Hide`. Described in the *New and Noteworthy* for the platform: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part1.php#quick-access

Comment: Thanks! Also for the link, it is very useful.

Comment: From my experience, under Windows 7 using Eclipse 4.4 upgraded from earlier versions, it was necessary to click in the border around the Quick Access text box to get to the "hide" option, rather than clicking in the box itself.

Comment: Not just on windows. On Linux as well, you have to clikck in the 'border'.